# When clicking a nested div, div returns parent ID. How do I return Child ID without taking parent ID?

Tags: jquery

I have code similar to this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery click events

```
$('#child1').click(function(){
var page = "value1";

    $('#content').hide();
    $('#content').load('includes/'+ page +'.php', function () {
        $('#content').fadeIn(speed);
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, when clicking on any of the content in the loaded #content ID the div children return the parent ID. How can I select the child ID while ignoring the parent?

The actual HTML is more complicated so the value of the child on the page wouldn't simply be #content#child1, is there a way to have the JS ignore #content and see #child1?

If I use code like

```
$('div').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    return false;
});
```

the value returned when clicking "#child1" or is "#content".

Comment: Please create a page on http://jsfiddle.net that reproduces issue

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where is the parent ID returned?

Comment: The issue is, when clicking a child div, using JQuery click event, the ID returned is of the parent not the child being clicked. I don't think I could replicate it on JSFiddle without the entirety of the code, beyond what I've included.

Comment: The ID is returned on click event. See my edit

Comment: your code should work as given

Comment: @cjcee: there is no "returns" in your code. Please create demo on jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8cXE/1/ it works

Comment: I added an example; of a simple on click event that returns the parent ID here.
[here](http://steps.cjchagnon.com) is the test site where the issue resides

Comment: @KaiQing the ('div') example was just to show how its returning the value. The actual code uses ('#child1') and ('#child2'). When clicking those divs the value returned is of the parent. not the div clicked.

Comment: I see. Try .live or .on instead - you are trying to read added content from an older method... $('#child1').on('click', function(){ ... });

Comment: @KaiQing [check out the live site linked previously](http://steps.cjchagnon.com) changing it to on click doesn't seem to resolve the returned value. The child divs in question are linked on every sub page called '#show1' and '#show2'. they are the two posters. if you click a link such as "about us" you will see the returned value.

Comment: Have you tried adding .on to show1 and show2 specifically and not using the selector param for .on while targeting content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be reading this wrong, but you've completely overwritten the the contents of `#content`.  The `#child1` and `#child2` divs no longer exist once the load command has completed.

Even if your loaded data includes a `#child1` div, it is not the same DOM node that you originally attached the click event to.  That old node is gone, replaced by your loaded data, and the event handlers are gone too.

If you want to keep listening to `#child1.click()` events after the old child nodes are deleted, you have two options:

- Re-bind events after the load completes
- Use event delegation on the `#content` node

Event delegation allows you to bind a listener on `#content` that will fire when events bubble up from the child elements:

```
$('#content').on('click', '#child1', function(evt) {
    // event handler here
    // this points to the element clicked ('#child1')
});
```

This will effectively keep your `#child1` click handler alive even after you have replaced the nodes with totally new HTML.