# jquery calling function in click event cause unwanted multiple calls of the function

Tags: jquery

I got folowing problem. what im tryin to do is to make a new TR each time i click on a button with ID #add_new_row. click event adds a row with a input inside which has CLASS p_pocet.
Before any clicks, i generate first TR on every page load, so i call function countPolozky() to give the input necessary BLUR function.
the problem is like this:
1) on first page load, i click in the only one input on page and i get alert with right value of the input of the row i clicked.
2) after i click a button to add a new row. jquery adds a new row and call the function countPolozky() again. (if i dont call it, the BLUR function reacts only on the first TR's input). if i click in the new TR's input, after i end focus, i get right alert again, BUT IF I CLICK ON THE FIRST TR, I GET 2 ALERTS. i want just one alert to get the value of the active row i clicked. 
if i add other rows, the alerts are just multiplying.

```
     ( function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("#add_new_row").click(function(){
                      var pocet = parseInt($("#tbl_rows_count").attr('value')) + 1;
                      $("#tbl_rows_count").val(pocet);
                      $("#add_new_row").before('<tr></td><td><input name="pocet[]" id="pocet'+                    pocet +'" class="polozky p_pocet" type="text" value="1.0"></td></tr>');
                      $(".add_news2").click(function(){
                          $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                      });
                      countPolozky();
                    });
                    countPolozky();
       });
    } ) 
( jQuery );

     function countPolozky()    
        {
            //$(".polozky").die("blur");
            $(".polozky").blur(function() {
                pocet = $(this).closest('tr').find('.p_pocet').val();
                alert(pocet);
            });    
        }
```

u can see the problem live here, its a website to make an invoice
at the end of the form there is inputs for adding ITEMS, here is the problem.
http://www.vzor-faktury.cz/#vygenerovat-fakturu

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. When you create a new element, bind a new event handler only to the new element, instead of everything `.polozky`.
2. Use event delegation.

Event delegation lets you set a single event handler on a container object (the table element for example) that will handle all blur events for all `.polozky` elements inside the table.  So you can dynamically add/modify/delete all the `.polozky` elements you want without having to bind new event handlers.

There's a few posts that talk about [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166602/when-clicking-a-nested-div-div-returns-parent-id-how-do-i-return-child-id-with) you can use as a reference.